# Is a verb transitive when used only with an indirect object?

Tags: transitive-verbs, direct-objects, intransitive-verbs, indirect-objects

I am learning about indirect objects and transitivity in French, but I believe that my question is also valid in English.  Therefore, I'd like to sort this out in English.

If a verb is used only with an indirect object (and no direct object), is that considered to be in transitive form?

For example, "I speak to Bob", not "I speak the truth to Bob".

Another example: "I walk to the store", not "I walk the dog to the store".

Comment: "Bob" and "the store" would normally not be considered indirect objects in those sentences. They might be called objects of the preposition, prepositional complements, etc.

Comment: Some verbs go both ways. Transitive when it takes a direct object, intransitive when it doesn't. Doesn't matter what it's doing in other circumstances. Object/Trans; No object/Intrans. When I speak and walk, I'm intransitive.

Comment: I may have opened a can of worms. The French lesson actually referred to [\[in\]direct object complements](https://www.colanguage.com/complement-object-french). I found this [likely counterpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_complement) in English, which doesn't seem to be a one-for-one counterpart. The French object complement page shows an example of an indirect object complement without a direct object complement; the verb usage is described as *transitive*.

Comment: I believe that my question doesn't make sense in English. I will delete it if no one weighs in with information to the contrary.

Comment: Indirect objects are defined quite differently in French and English. You can't assume that the rules for French are anything like the rules for English.

Comment: I was planning to erase this question, but it occurred to me that what I found in my comment above might prevent someone else from wandering down the wrong path as I did.  Unless someone can think of a reason not to, I will post as the answer the differences between French and English.

Answer (score 0):

No.

MW

transitive (adjective)

1: **characterized by having or containing a *direct object*.** A transitive verb

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't the one who marked your answer down.  In the comments under my question, I speculated that my question is poorly posed, as the actual French lesson refers to object *complements*.  What I found about this in English is not an exact counterpart.  The webpage on French object complements says that a verb is *transitive* if it takes an indirect object complement and no direct object complement. I may delete the question unless I get some feedback that it actually adds value.